# Commerce: programmatically create new product with my ID

Tags: commerce, entities

I have database of products and I want to export it to Drupal Commerce database with my Ids being saved:

```
$product = commerce_product_new('product');
$product->product_id = '100500';
$product->title = 'my title';
commerce_product_save($product);
```

But it always returns STATUS_UPDATE because in sites/all/modules/commerce/modules/product/includes/commerce_product.controller.inc in line 80 there is:

```
// Determine if we will be inserting a new product.
$product->is_new = empty($product->product_id);
```

It always clears "is_new" when "product_id" is filled.

If I change that string like:

```
$product->is_new = !empty($product->is_new) || empty($product->product_id);
```

Everything works fine.

Is it a Commerce bug or I do something wrong?

Comment: I doubt you can not say it new when product has already id associated with it.

Comment: id comes from different database, it has to be the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this as a bug, as we do want to prevent arbitrary IDs from being set in general. If you're doing it intentionally, though, I think your best bet would be to implement an override in a custom entity controller that extends the core functionality and changes the behavior of the is_new check like you've done.